# scanf Прочитать float с запятой

Tags: c, float, scanf

Возможно базовый вопрос, но я никак не могу найти ответа. Как прочитать из консоли float написанный с запятой, а не точкой.

Если просто писать: `scanf("%f", &val);` и вводить например `1.5`, то в переменную val он запишет только `1`

Comment: Это проблемы с locale, в русской локали разделителем дробной части считается запятая.

Comment: @avp Огромно спасибо! Помогли

Comment: @avp, почему не ответом?)

Comment: @eanmos, такой объем для ответа просто смешон -)

Comment: @avp, ну если еще написать, как поменять локаль, то самое то)

Comment: @eanmos, не могу же я писать ответ, не проверив его. А русская локаль у меня даже не установлена... Напишите сами. `setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus-locale-name");` если при ней хочется вводить числа с точкой, то потом `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");` Кажется так, но нужно проверять